# Correct way to compute denominator in the bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, likelihood

Say I have two data points and two Gaussians that these might be coming from. What is my evidence in this case?

1. $P(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{2} (p(xi|\mu1)p(\mu1) + p(xi|\mu2)p(\mu2)) $ Because my samples are iid and I write the probability of each of them as the product of individual probabilities of each data point and then I break each down to be coming from the two Gaussians
2. $P(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{2} p(xi|\mu1)p(\mu1) + \prod_{i=1}^{2} p(xi|\mu2)p(\mu2) $ Because, I consider my entire data in one swoop as $D$ and then break the probabilities down using $P(D|\mu)p(\mu)$ and then write each term as the product of individual data point probabilities (basically, separate $D$ as a product of individual data point probabilites)